# How to change URL path in react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I use several route in my app And I have  conditions for bringing information in that route.
I created an array and the array values are created according to those conditions.
Part of my code:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
                var arr = res[i];
                switch (arr) {                 
                    case "MsgManagementTab":
                        routearray.push({path :"/main/messages" ,component:<Messages isSidebarActive={this.state.isSidebarActive} />})     
                      break;
                    case "AlgorithmManagementTab":
                        routearray.push({path :"/main/algorithms",component:<Algorithm isSidebarActive={this.state.isSidebarActive}/>})
                      break;
                    case "SocialNetworkManagementTab":
                        routearray.push({path :"/main/socialNetworks",component:<SocialNetWork isSidebarActive={this.state.isSidebarActive}/>})
                  }
               }
```

and :

```
   <Switch>
     {this.state.routearray ?this.state.routearray.map(item=>{
return <Route path={item.path}>{item.component}</Route>
   </Switch>
```

In this case, for example, I have access to the Route of the message when the `MsgManagementTab` exists.
What I want to do is if the `MsgManagementTab` does not exist, and if the user wants to go to the page via URL, go to the path I want to be redirected to.
This is the path I want to redirected :

```
 <Route path="/main/access/deny"><NoAccess  isSidebarActive={this.state.isSidebarActive} /></Route>
```

Someone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question/issue, you want the app to redirect from "/main/messages" to "/main/access/deny" when the `Switch` ***isn't*** rendering the `Route` for "/main/messages".

## Solution

*After* the mapped routes include a `Redirect` component to redirect ***from*** a specific path ***to*** another path. This works by allowing the `Switch` to match the `Route` for "/main/messages" first if it exists, otherwise since that route won't be available the `Redirect` will handle it.

[Redirect from](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect/from-string)

```
<Switch>
  ...

  {this.state.routearray ? this.state.routearray.map(item => (
    <Route path={item.path}>{item.component}</Route>
  ))}

  ...

  <Redirect from="/main/messages" to="/main/access/deny />

  ...

  <Route path="/main/access/deny">
    <NoAccess isSidebarActive={this.state.isSidebarActive} />
  </Route>

  ...
</Switch>
```